# ServiceStack .Net Core fluent validation Not consistent with full .NET 4.6.2

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

So we have a working ServiceStack service hosted inside a Windows Service using .Net 4.6.2, which uses a bunch of Fluent Validation validators.

We would like to port this to .Net Core. So I started to create cut down project just with a few of the features of our main app to see what the port to .Net Core would be like.

Most things are fine, such as

- IOC
- Routing
- Hosting
- Endpoint is working

The thing that does not seem to be correct is validation. To illustrate this I will walk through some existing .Net 4.6.2 code and then the .Net Core code. Where I have included the results for both

**.NET 4.6.2 example**

This is all good when using the full .Net 4.6.2 framework and the various ServiceStack Nuget packages.

For example I have this basic Dto (please ignore the strange name, long story not my choice)

```
using ServiceStack;

namespace .RiskStore.ApiModel.Analysis
{
    [Route("/analysis/run", "POST")]
    public class AnalysisRunRequest : BaseRequest, IReturn<AnalysisRunResponse>
    {
        public AnalysisPart Analysis { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Where we have this base class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace .RiskStore.ApiModel
{
    public abstract class BaseRequest
    {
        public string CreatedBy { get; set;}
    }
}
```

And we have this validator (we have way more than this working in .Net 4.6.2 app, this is just to show differences between full .Net and .Net Core which we will see in a minute)

```
using .RiskStore.ApiModel.Analysis;
using ServiceStack.FluentValidation;

namespace .RiskStore.ApiServer.Validators.Analysis
{
    public class AnalysisRunRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<AnalysisRunRequest>
    {
        public AnalysisRunRequestValidator(AnalysisPartValidator analysisPartValidator)
        {

            RuleFor(analysis => analysis.CreatedBy)
                .Must(HaveGoodCreatedBy)
                .WithMessage("CreatedBy MUST be 'sbarber'")
                .WithErrorCode(ErrorCodes.ValidationErrorCode);
        }


        private bool HaveGoodCreatedBy(AnalysisRunRequest analysisRunRequest, string createdBy)
        {

            return createdBy == "sbarber";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my host file for this service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Funq;
using .RiskStore.ApiModel.Analysis;
using .RiskStore.ApiModel.Analysis.Results;
using .RiskStore.ApiServer.Api.Analysis;
using .RiskStore.ApiServer.Exceptions;
using .RiskStore.ApiServer.IOC;
using .RiskStore.ApiServer.Services;
using .RiskStore.ApiServer.Services.Results;
using .RiskStore.ApiServer.Validators.Analysis;
using .RiskStore.ApiServer.Validators.Analysis.Results;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.AnalysisRun.Repositories.Results;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.AnalysisRun.Repositories.Search;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.AnalysisRun.Repositories.Validation;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.Configuration;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.Connectivity;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.Ingestion.Repositories.EventSet;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.JobLog.Repositories;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.StaticData.Repositories;
using .RiskStore.DataAccess.UnitOfWork;
using .RiskStore.Toolkit.Configuration;
using .RiskStore.Toolkit.Jobs.Repositories;
using .RiskStore.Toolkit.Storage;
using .RiskStore.Toolkit.Utils;
using .Toolkit;
using .Toolkit.Configuration;
using .Toolkit.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using ServiceStack.Validation;

namespace .RiskStore.ApiServer.Api
{
    public class ApiServerHttpHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<ApiServerHttpHost>();
        public static string RoutePrefix => "analysisapi";

        /// <summary>
        /// Base constructor requires a Name and Assembly where web service implementation is located
        /// </summary>
        public ApiServerHttpHost()
            : base(typeof(ApiServerHttpHost).FullName, typeof(AnalysisServiceStackService).Assembly)
        {
            _log.Debug("ApiServerHttpHost constructed");
        }

        public override void SetConfig(HostConfig config)
        {
            base.SetConfig(config);

            JsConfig.TreatEnumAsInteger = true;
            JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
            JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
            JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;
            JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString();
            JsConfig<Guid>.DeSerializeFn = Guid.Parse;
            config.HandlerFactoryPath = RoutePrefix;

            var exceptionMappings = new Dictionary<Type, int>
            {
                {typeof(JobServiceException), 400},
                {typeof(NullReferenceException), 400},
            };

            config.MapExceptionToStatusCode = exceptionMappings;
            _log.Debug("ApiServerHttpHost SetConfig ok");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Application specific configuration
        /// This method should initialize any IoC resources utilized by your web service classes.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            //Config examples
            //this.Plugins.Add(new PostmanFeature());
            //this.Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());

            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

            container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AnalysisRunRequestValidator).Assembly);

            .......
            .......
            .......
            .......


            container.Register<AnalysisPartValidator>(c => new AnalysisPartValidator(
                    c.Resolve<AnalysisDealPartLinkingModelEventSetValidator>(),
                    c.Resolve<AnalysisOutputSettingsPartValidMetaRisksValidator>(),
                    c.Resolve<AnalysisOutputSettingsGroupPartValidMetaRisksValidator>(),
                    c.Resolve<AnalysisDealPartCollectionValidator>(),
                    c.Resolve<AnalysisPortfolioPartCollectionValidator>(),
                    c.Resolve<UniqueCombinedOutputSettingsPropertiesValidator>()))
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);

            container.Register<AnalysisRunRequestValidator>(c => new AnalysisRunRequestValidator(c.Resolve<AnalysisPartValidator>()))
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);


            _log.Debug("ApiServerHttpHost Configure ok");

            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json
            });
        }}
}
```

So I then hit this endpoint with this JSON

```
{
    "Analysis": {
        //Not important for discussion
        //Not important for discussion
        //Not important for discussion
        //Not important for discussion
    },
    "CreatedBy": "frank"
}
```

And I get this response in PostMan tool (which I was expecting)

[image]

So that's all good.

**.NET Core example**

So now lets see what its like in .Net core example.

Lets start with the request dto

```
using System;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo.Model.Core
{
    [Route("/analysis/run", "POST")]
    public class AnalysisRunRequest : BaseRequest, IReturn<AnalysisRunResponse>
    {
        public AnalysisDto Analysis { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which uses this base request object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo.Model.Core
{
    public abstract class BaseRequest
    {
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the same validator we used from .NET 4.6.2 example, but in my .Net Core code instead

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ServiceStack.Demo.Model.Core;
using ServiceStack.FluentValidation;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo.Core.Validators
{
    public class AnalysisRunRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<AnalysisRunRequest>
    {
        public AnalysisRunRequestValidator(AnalysisDtoValidator analysisDtoValidator)
        {

            RuleFor(analysis => analysis.CreatedBy)
                .Must(HaveGoodCreatedBy)
                .WithMessage("CreatedBy MUST be 'sbarber'")
                .WithErrorCode(ErrorCodes.ValidationErrorCode);
        }

        private bool HaveGoodCreatedBy(AnalysisRunRequest analysisRunRequest, string createdBy)
        {

            return createdBy == "sbarber";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my host code for .Net core example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Funq;
using ServiceStack.Demo.Core.Api.Analysis;
using ServiceStack.Demo.Core.IOC;
using ServiceStack.Demo.Core.Services;
using ServiceStack.Demo.Core.Validators;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using ServiceStack.Validation;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo.Core.Api
{
    public class ApiServerHttpHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public static string RoutePrefix => "analysisapi";

        public ApiServerHttpHost()
            : base(typeof(ApiServerHttpHost).FullName, typeof(AnalysisServiceStackService).GetAssembly())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ApiServerHttpHost constructed");
        }

        public override void SetConfig(HostConfig config)
        {
            base.SetConfig(config);

            JsConfig.TreatEnumAsInteger = true;
            JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
            JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
            JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;
            JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString();
            JsConfig<Guid>.DeSerializeFn = Guid.Parse;
            config.HandlerFactoryPath = RoutePrefix;

            var exceptionMappings = new Dictionary<Type, int>
            {
                {typeof(NullReferenceException), 400},
            };

            config.MapExceptionToStatusCode = exceptionMappings;
            Console.WriteLine("ApiServerHttpHost SetConfig ok");
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            //Config examples
            //this.Plugins.Add(new PostmanFeature());
            //this.Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());

            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

            container.RegisterValidators(typeof(ApiServerHttpHost).GetAssembly());


            container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<DateProvider, IDateProvider>()
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Container);


            container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<FakeRepository, IFakeRepository>()
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Container);


            container.Register<LifetimeScopeManager>(cont => new LifetimeScopeManager(cont))
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Hierarchy);



            container.Register<DummySettingsPropertiesValidator>(c => new DummySettingsPropertiesValidator(c.Resolve<LifetimeScopeManager>()))
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);

            container.Register<AnalysisDtoValidator>(c => new AnalysisDtoValidator(
                    c.Resolve<DummySettingsPropertiesValidator>()))
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);

            container.Register<AnalysisRunRequestValidator>(c => new AnalysisRunRequestValidator(c.Resolve<AnalysisDtoValidator>()))
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);


            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json
            });


        }
    }
}
```

And this is me trying to now hit the .Net Core endpoint with the same bad JSON payload as demonstrated above with the .Net 4.6.2 example, which gave correct Http response (i.e included error that I was expecting in response)

Anyway here is payload being sent to .Net Core endpoint

```
{
    "Analysis": {
        //Not important for discussion
        //Not important for discussion
        //Not important for discussion
        //Not important for discussion
    },
    "CreatedBy": "frank"
}
```

Where we can see that we are getting into the .Net Core example validator code just fine

[image]

But this time I get a very different Http response (one that I was not expecting at all). I get this

[image]

It can be seen that we do indeed get the correct Status code of "400" (failed) which is good. But we **DO NOT** get anything about the validation failure at all.

I was expecting this to give me the same http response as the original .Net 4.6.2 example above.

But what I seem to be getting back is the JSON representing the **AnalysisRunResponse**. Which looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo.Model.Core
{
    public class AnalysisRunResponse : BaseResponse
    {

        public Guid AnalysisUid { get; set; }

    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ServiceStack.Demo.Model.Core
{
    public abstract class BaseResponse
    {
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I thought the way ServiceStack works (in fact that is how it works for ALL our existing .Net 4.6.2 code) is that the validation is done first, **if AND ONLY if it passes validation is the actual route code run**

But this .Net core example seems to not work like that.

I have a break point set in Visual Studio for the actual route and Console.WriteLine(..) but that is never hit and I never see the result of the Console.WriteLine(..)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you enable `Config.DebugMode` and provide the full raw HTTP Request / Response Headers using a tool like Web Inspector, Fiddler or WireShark. Note you don't need to specify `ReuseScope.Hierarchy` which is the default and you're only using a single Container Instance so `ReuseScope.Container` is redundant as well.

Comment: Mythz: sure I'll do that in morning

Comment: Actually Mythz what I will do is put it up on GitHub so you can see full code. Does that work for you? We are paying customer obviously, and have license. So its a genuine support request type of thing

Comment: Mthyz uploaded the stuff to here : https://github.com/sachabarber/ServiceStackCoreValidationIssue

Comment: This doesn't build, it looks like it's missing an entire Project Reference?

Comment: That's bizarre, must be pixies in the git pipeline, let me check in morning

Comment: Ah yes my bad, didn't add model project Grrr....I'll fix tgat 1St thing tomorrow morning I'm sorry about that. Shameful behaviour

Comment: Mythz, sorry about that try that repo now. Should be all there

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to any longer an issue with the [latest v5 of ServiceStack](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749) that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

As sending this request:

[image]

Is returning the expected response:

[image]

The .NET Core packages are [merged with the main packages in ServiceStack v5](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749) so you'll need to remove the `.Core` prefix to download them, i.e:

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="5.*" />
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Server" Version="5.*" />
```

You'll also need to [add ServiceStack's MyGet feed](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) to fetch the latest ServiceStack v5 NuGet packages which you can do by adding this [NuGet.config](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/react-spa/blob/master/NuGet.Config) in the same folder as your `.sln`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="ServiceStack MyGet feed" value="https://www.myget.org/F/servicestack" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yeah that worked. I would not have know to use this MyGet source, guess it pays to reads the docs. Thanks for the help there

Comment: @sacha no probs, the MyGet feed is what holds the latest pre-release packages for the next version of ServiceStack.